# ASP.NET MVC 6 : Don't reload all dlls for a slight modification in the code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Using ASP.NET MVC 6 with Visual Studio 2017, each time i modify a controller or a class, i need to recompile the code, and so all the dlls i use (and they are plenty) are compiled too.
I wait about 3 minutes each time and it destroys my productivity.
How to avoid it ?

I've already put the tag "optimizeCompilation".

Comment: I have been struggling with similar compile times and have noticed that if I disable Realtime Protection in Windows Defender then 3 minutes drops to about 30 seconds -- I am very curious if you see a similar improvement.  I have not been able to figure out how to achieve the same effective setup using either path exclusions or an EXE exclusion in the Defender UI (but this is supposed to be possible).  And Defender will turn Realtime protection back on sooner or later whether you like it or not.

Comment: Wow man. As you said, i dropped to 30 seconds. Thanks ! Completely absurd. An exclusion could be a permanent solution to the automatic reactivation of this Realtime protection ?

Comment: I think I am going to post a question over on superuser.  i'd like to get this properly configured using exclusions.